# ArrayList char and subclass

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char

I'm having an issue of trying to iterate through a `String`, and adding each `Character` to an `ArrayList<Letter>`.  I'm just not understanding something.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Phrase {
    private String phrase;
    private ArrayList<Letter> letters;
    public String getPhrase() {
        return phrase;
    }
    public ArrayList<Letter> getLetters() {
        return letters;
    }

    public Phrase(String phrZ){
        phrase = phrZ.toUpperCase();
        letters = new ArrayList<>();
        for (char i : phrase.toCharArray()){
            letters.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I get not applicable for arguments error.

Letter class:

```
public class Letter {
    private char letter;
    private boolean isHidden;

    public Letter(char letR){
        letter = letR;
        if (String.valueOf(letter).matches("[A-Z]")){
            isHidden = true;
        }
        if (String.valueOf(letter).matches("\\p{Punct}")){
            isHidden = false;
        }
    }

    public char getLetter(){

        return letter;
    }

    public boolean isHidden(){

        return isHidden;
    }

    public void unhide(){
        isHidden = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you try and add a `char` to a list of `Letter`s; no wonder why it fails. And what is `Letter` anyway?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `letters.add(new Letter(i));`?

Comment: Show the `Letter` class definition.

Comment: You can use List<Character>

Comment: Sorry, added Letter Class. I was told to add each character of string to ArrayList<Letter>

Comment: Is this code compiling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
letters.add(new Letter(i));
```

instead of

```
letters.add(i);
```

To add an object of type letter into the arraylist `letters`, you need to make an object of letter first and then add it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm losing my mind lately, simplest things are escaping me.